# Replace the page from a url using php

Tags: php, string

I have this type of urls stored in a php variable:

```
$url1 = 'https://localhost/mywebsite/help&action=something';
$url2 = 'https://localhost/mywebsite/jobs&action=one#profil';
$url3 = 'https://localhost/mywebsite/info&action=two&action2=something2';
$url4 = 'https://localhost/mywebsite/contact&action=one&action2=two#profil';
```

I want to replace the page `help, jobs, info, contact` with `home` in a very simple way, something like this:

```
echo replaceUrl($url1);
https://localhost/mywebsite/home&action=something

echo replaceUrl($url2);
https://localhost/mywebsite/home&action=one#profil

echo replaceUrl($url3);
https://localhost/mywebsite/home&action=two&action2=something2

echo replaceUrl($url4);
https://localhost/mywebsite/home&action=one&action2=two#profil
```

Comment: Are you looking for PHP code to change the actual string, for example if you are trying to load this page from within PHP. Or are you wanting to use something like an Apache rewrite rule to serve the second page when the first one is requested?

Comment: And exactly how are you generating these links? By typing them into the address bar, or by something a bit more dynamic?

Comment: Some elaboration would be nice.

Comment: Ah, see. Tags do wonders. Edit: or not.

Comment: wait, so you're always going to replace on that same place?, is that replacement on the same place always?

Comment: @paulalexandru no what i mean is, in that url, you're going to replace always on that exact same place? you're not going to replace for example `mywebsite` or `&action=something`, just that segment which is `home`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is the solution i found:

```
function replaceUrl($page){
    $pieces = explode("/", $page);
    $base = '';

    for ($i=0; $i<count($pieces)-1; $i++) $base .= $pieces[$i].'/';

    $hash = strpbrk($pieces[count($pieces)-1], '&#');

    return $base.'home'.$hash;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You'll want to add something like

```
RedirectMatch 301 help(.*) home$1
```

to your .htaccess file. I'm not sure PHP is the correct tool for the job.

Answer (score -1):

If you actually want to modify a *string* with the value of that (which is what your tags and.. comments indicate), you'll want to do:

```
$url = "https://localhost/mywebsite/help&action=something#profil"
$url = str_replace("help", "home", $url);
echo $url; // https://localhost/mywebsite/home&action=something#profil
```